# Problemas al mostrar la fecha

Tags: php, mysql

Para hacer la conexión de base de datos lo tengo de esta manera:

```
<?php

class ConexionBD{

    public function cBD(){

        $bd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=viajesfya", "root", "");

        $bd->exec("SET lc_time_names = 'es_PE'");
        return $bd;
    }
}

?>
```

El controlador lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```
public function VerCitasDetalladoC() {

  $tablaBD = "vueloslogistica";
  $resultado = CitasM::VerCitasDetalladoM($tablaBD);
  return $resultado;
}
```

y finalmente el modelo esta así:

```
static public function VerCitasDetalladoM($tablaBD) {

  $pdo = ConexionBD::cBD() - > prepare("SELECT id, id_padre, id_consulta, id_logistica ,nyaP, documento, colegio, comentario, DATE_FORMAT(inicio, '%W %d de %M de %Y') AS inicio, DATE_FORMAT(inicio, '%h:%m:%s %p') AS Hora_Inicio, DATE_FORMAT(fin, '%W %d de %M de %Y') AS fin, DATE_FORMAT(fin, '%h:%m:%s %p') AS Hora_Fin, color FROM $tablaBD");
  $pdo - > execute();
  return $pdo - > fetchAll();

  $pdo - > close();
  $pdo = null;

}
```

Al mostrase en mi tabla sale de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema son los acentos, cual es el charset de la DB y del archivo que muestra tus vistas?

Comment: @Antonio-Galicia los snippets solo sirven para HTML + CSS +JS. Un código en PHP no es ejecutable desde aquí.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la codificación: esto te impide mostrar los **acentos o tildes**. Cambia la codificación a UTF8, en tu cadena de conexión:

**Primer Ejemplo:**
Constante *MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND* a la conexión de la base de datos con pdo.

```
$pdo = new PDO(
  'mysql:host=mihost;dbname=mibd',
  'miusuario',
  'mipassword',
  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8")
);
```

**Segundo ejemplo:** Lo tendrías que declarar en tu cadena de conexión con base de datos como:

```
"mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=utf8"
```

Antes de la versión PHP 5.3.6, la opción charset fue ignorada. Si por alguna razón estás ejecutando una versión anterior de PHP, debes declarar así al UTF-8:

```
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:$connstr",  $user, $password);
$dbh->exec("set names utf8");
```